# Not able to run IOS app on Simulator via Appium - M1 chipset (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, appium, ios-simulator, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

We want to launch IOS application for Automation but getting below error only for Simulator. For Android, appium is working fine.

Xcode version : 12.5
MacOS - M1 Chipset 11.0.1 (big Sur)
Appium version: 1.22.0-beta.0
Simulator version- 14.5

> [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
> [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
> [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
> [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
> [XCUITest] {}
> ----- Exception in Starting Driver ------
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details.
> Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing
> the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because
> of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
> xcodebuild error message:
>
> ```
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
> System info: host: '197NODMB27871.local', ip: '2405:201:5002:7087:bd47:b227:2c88:f122%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
> ```
>
> os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
> Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to
> launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed
> with code 65
> xcodebuild error message:
>
> ```
>    at getResponseForW3CError (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
>     at asyncHandler (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
> System info: host: '197NODMB27871.local', ip: '2405:201:5002:7087:bd47:b227:2c88:f122%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
> ```
>
> os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
> Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
> at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
> at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:88)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:98)
> at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:90)
> at com.one97.paytm.appautomation.ios.GenericFunctionsIOS.startDriver(GenericFunctionsIOS.java:116)
> at com.one97.paytm.appautomation.runnable.StartDriverRunnable.startDriverAndPutInPool_IOS(StartDriverRunnable.java:136)
> at com.one97.paytm.appautomation.runnable.StartDriverRunnable.startDriverAndPutInPool(StartDriverRunnable.java:92)
> at com.one97.paytm.appautomation.runnable.StartDriverRunnable.run(StartDriverRunnable.java:74)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
> ... 20 more
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
> error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure:
> xcodebuild failed with code 65
> xcodebuild error message:
>
> ```
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
> System info: host: '197NODMB27871.local', ip: '2405:201:5002:7087:bd47:b227:2c88:f122%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X',
> ```
>
> os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
> Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
> remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to
> launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed
> with code 65
> xcodebuild error message:
>
> ```
>     at getResponseForW3CError (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
>     at asyncHandler (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> DeviceName = Automation-Simulator-1, DeviceID = 7EF63B02-3CE5-4C38-85CB-017A60A43568, DeviceVersion = 14.5
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>   at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
>   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
>   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
>   at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
>   ... 25 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 0
> ```